# fetch title value with punctuation using useParams in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, parameters

I want to fetch the title value from the URL. But the problem is title value contains punctuation. For example: "Who's Available? [April 2022]". useParams can't fetch the full title from the URL.

How can I fetch this full title name from the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding the title value in the URL, it needs to be URL Encoded in order for `useParams` to correctly read it.

In your example it whould be

```
url.com/?title=Who%27s%20Available%3F%20%5BApril%202022%5D
```

When setting it from code you can achieve it by using `URLSearchParams` or libraries like `qs` to encode your strings